# Trying to change a link on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three buttons and i want such tha when i click on one button the link on an `a` tag changes

```
<a  class="payverlink" href="exbronzeregistrationform.php">Continue to registration</a>

<button class="goldpac">Choose Plan</button>
<button class="silverpac">Choose Plan</button>
<button class="bronzepac">Choose Plan</button>
```

I want such that when i click on one button, it changes the link at `.payverlink`

I have tried

```
function bronze()
    {
        $('.payverlink').href="exbronzeregistrationform.php";
    }
    function silver()
    {
        $('.payverlink').href="exsilverregistrationform.php";
    }

<button class="silverpac" onclick="silver()">Choose Plan</button>
<button class="bronzepac" onclick="bronze()">Choose Plan</button>
```

But this changes to bronze function onclick of any of the buttons. Please whats the issue.

Comment: You can use jQuery `attr` : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Tried that also `$('.bronzepac').click(function () {
             $('.payverlink').setAttribute('href', 'exbronzeregistrationform.php');
         });
         $('.silverpac').click(function () {
             $('.payverlink').setAttribute('href', 'exsilverregistrationform.php');
        });` .but thisalso had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You could set your javascript code to trigger the button click and avoid using the onclick into html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").on('click', function(){

       if ($(this).hasClass('goldpac')) {
           window.location="http://..."; /* or exbronzeregistrationform.php for example */
       } else if ($(this).hasClass('silverpac')) {
           window.location="http://..."; /* or exbronzeregistrationform.php for example */
       } else if ($(this).hasClass('bronzepac')) {
           window.location="http://..."; /* or exbronzeregistrationform.php for example */
       }
   });
});
```

You could add one more line in each case changing the a tag, but ti wont make a huge difference in your actions as it isn't used as you click the buttons.

`$("a.payverlink").attr("href", "http://....");  /* or exbronzeregistrationform.php for example */`

So, you could just remove the 'href' as you contantly will change the url from js.

Answer (score 1):

Use attr or prop, attr stands for attribute and prop for property!

```js
$(
  function(){
    $('#google').attr('href', 'https://duckduckgo.com/');
    //or use prop
    $('#duckduckgo').prop('href', 'https://bing.com')
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="header"></h1>
<a id="google" href="https://google.com/">google is down!</a>
<br>
<a id="duckduckgo" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">I'm slow...</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that both functions are failing, since there is no such property href on JQuery object.

Use this approach instead:

```
$('.payverlink').prop("href","exbronzeregistrationform.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try .prop() method of jQuery hopefully it works .

```
function bronze()
{
    $('.payverlink').prop('href','exbronzeregistrationform.php');
}
function silver()
{
    $('.payverlink').prop('href','exsilverregistrationform.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.attr` function:

```js
function bronze(){
  changeLink('exbronzeregistrationform');
}
function silver(){
  changeLink('exsilverregistrationform.php');
}

function changeLink(url){
  $('.payverlink').attr('href',url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a  class="payverlink" href="exbronzeregistrationform.php">Continue to registration</a>

<button class="silverpac" onclick="silver()">Choose Plan silverpac</button>
<button class="bronzepac" onclick="bronze()">Choose Plan bronzepac</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function bronze()
{
    $('.payverlink').attr("href","exbronzeregistrationform.php");
}
function silver()
{
    $('.payverlink').attr("href","exsilverregistrationform.php");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  class="payverlink" href="exbronzeregistrationform.php">Continue to registration</a>

<button class="goldpac">Choose Plan</button>
<button class="silverpac" onclick="silver()">Choose Plan</button>
<button class="bronzepac" onclick="bronze()">Choose Plan</button>
```

You can try this. it will helps you. :)